# Change svg element background color via checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to change the background colour of a SVG image via checkbox selection.  (checkbox select changes background colour and un-select changes it back)

```css
#hand {
  fill: #FF0000;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#foot {
  fill: #00CC00;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#head {
  fill: #0099FF;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hand" id="hand" />hand</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="foot" id="foot" />Foot</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="head" id="head" />Head</td>
    <td>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
      <svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 300;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .st0{font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular';}
        .st1{fill:none;}
        .st2{font-size:12;}
        .st3{fill:#EEEEEE;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

    ]]>
    </style>
    <rect id="head" x="216.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect id="foot" x="130.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect id="hand" x="44.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect x="44.5" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.839"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.1567 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Hand</text>
    <rect x="130.326" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.838"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 161.0044 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Foot</text>
    <rect x="216.325" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.838"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 245.3066 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Head</text>
    </svg>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi. As written, you haven't actually asked a question. What are you trying to do and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you can use the `change` event to listen to the checkbox changes and then set a selected attribute to the `rect`. I have also updated your CSS to handle the selected attribute state.

```js
(function() {
  $('input').change(e => {
    const isChecked = e.currentTarget.checked;
    const name = $(e.currentTarget).attr('name');
    $(`#${name}`).attr('selected', isChecked)
  });
})();
```

```css
#hand[selected] {
  fill: #FF0000;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#foot[selected] {
  fill: #00CC00;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#head[selected] {
  fill: #0099FF;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="hand" />hands</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="foot" />Foot</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="head" />Head</td>
    <td>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
      <svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 300;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .st0{font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular';}
        .st1{fill:none;}
        .st2{font-size:12;}
        .st3{fill:#EEEEEE;stroke:#CCCCCC;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

    ]]>
    </style>
    <rect id="head" x="216.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect id="foot" x="130.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect id="hand" x="44.5" y="95.5" class="st3" width="84" height="46"/>
    <rect x="44.5" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.839"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.1567 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Hand</text>
    <rect x="130.326" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.838"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 161.0044 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Foot</text>
    <rect x="216.325" y="102.888" class="st1" width="84.35" height="10.838"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 245.3066 111.4082)" class="st0 st2">Head</text>
    </svg>
  </tr>
</table>
```